# Having problem building react-native app with expo in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo

I have successfully built my app in android. But when I am running the command `expo run:ios` on macOS Ventura 13.6, I am having the following error:

"Error downloading and extracting template package: Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 243
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/private/var/folders/qw/slkn0lcd7d111ywhy1frhff00000gn/T/9660f69bdb9f9887f19a06c8b726844f/ios'"

I have tried deleting the node_modules and yarn.lock with no luck. Can someone please hint me about my next possible steps?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that directory or its subdirectories are not in your `.gitignore` file.